# Get checked checkboxes values from a form with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Just trying to learn by myself how to make a form and I'm currently stuck with checkboxes.

When submitting, my form is sending an mail to a specific address (currently working).

However, I cannot get all the checked checkboxes values selected by user; I get 'undefined' in my mail. Please see as below my html/js/php part of code. Please be as simple as possible as I am a full begginer.

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Start Contact -->
    <div id="contact" class="contact-box">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="title-box">
                        <h2>Confirmez-nous votre présence</h2>
                        <p>On a hâte d'y être. Et vous ? </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="contact-block">
                    <form method="POST" action="form-process.php" id="contactForm">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nom & Prénom" required data-error="Merci d'entrer votre nom et prénom.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Adresse mail" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-error="Merci d'entrer votre adresse mail.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="custom-select d-block form-control" id="adulte" name="adulte" required data-error="Merci d'indiquer le nombre d'invités adultes.">
                                  <option disabled selected value>Nombre d'invités adultes*</option>
                                  <option value="1">Juste moi !</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="custom-select d-block form-control" id="enfant" name="enfant" required data-error="Merci d'indiquer le nombre d'invités enfants.">
                                  <option disabled selected value>Nombre d'invités enfants*</option>
                                  <option value="Aucun">Aucun !</option>
                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        Je serai présent(e) / Nous serons présent(e)s :*
                         <table class="form-control" style="background-color: #e6eceb; height: 210px" id="event">
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="mairie" id="CheckboxGroup1">
                             Cérémonie civile</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="vin d'honneur" id="CheckboxGroup2">
                             À la santé des mariés !</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="église" id="CheckboxGroup3">
                             Cérémonie religieuse</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="dîner" id="CheckboxGroup4">
                             Dîner</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="brunch" id="CheckboxGroup5">
                             Brunch BBQ</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td><label>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="aucun" id="CheckboxGroup6">
                             Malheureusement indisponible(s)</label></td>
                           </tr>
                         </table>
                                                </div>
                           </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="msg" placeholder="Une information à nous communiquer ? Le nom des gens accompagnant ? Végan, végétarien ou simplement au régime ?" rows="8" data-error="Une information à nous communiquer ? Le nom des personnes accompagnatrices ? Végan, végétarien ou simplement au régime ? Une musique qui vous ambiance ?" ></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="submit-button text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Envoyer la confirmation</button>
                                <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
                                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>            
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Contact -->
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Le formulaire est incomplet.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    //var name = $("#name").val();
    //var email = $("#email").val();
    //var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
    //var message = $("#message").val();
    //var adulte = document.getElementById('adulte').value;
    //var enfant = document.getElementById('enfant').value;
    
    var formData = new FormData(event.target);
    var checkedOnes = formData.getAll("choice[]");
    var name = formData.get("name");
    var email = formData.get("email");
    var message = formData.get("msg");
    var adulte = formData.get("adulte");
    var enfant = formData.get("enfant");
    var data = { name, email, message, adulte, enfant, checkedOnes: checkedOnes.toString() };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        //data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&msg_subject=" + msg_subject + "&message=" + message + "&adulte=" + adulte + "&enfant=" + enfant + "&choice=" + strChkOnes,
        data: data,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message envoyé !")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Nom et prénom requis ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email requis ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MSG Guest
if (empty($_POST["adulte"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Nombre d'invités adultes requis ";
} else {
    $adulte = $_POST["adulte"];
}

if (empty($_POST["enfant"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Nombre d'invités enfants requis ";
} else {
    $enfant = $_POST["enfant"];
}

// MSG Event
//if (empty($_POST["event"])) {
//    $errorMSG .= "Détails de votre présence requis ";
//} else {
//    $event = $_POST["event"];
//}
$checkedOnes = $_POST["checkedOnes"];

// MESSAGE
//if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
//    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
//} else {
//    $message = $_POST["message"];
//}
$message = $_POST["message"];


$EmailTo = "xxx@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Nouvelle confirmation de présence";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Nom : ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email : ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Adulte(s) : ";
$Body .= $adulte;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Enfant(s) : ";
$Body .= $enfant;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Présent(s) à : ";
$Body .= $checkedOnes;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message : ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Un problème est survenu :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Currently, the mail looks perfect except that, next to 'event :' I got undefined... :'(

Comment: Your checkboxes are called `choice` so why are you checking for `event` in your PHP? `event` is the table which is just a HTML element - only inputs are submitted in a form.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Can you explain _checking for `event` in your PHP_? Pretty sure I got your point but not sure what should I change then?

Comment: I have changed `event` by `checkedvalue` in js. What should I change then in PHP?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Just began with that as I'm trying to build my wedding website by my own. I'll have a look at serialize then if you say so.

Comment: @IncredibleHat  that's pretty advanced for someone who has only just started teaching themselves how to do forms! Let them learn the basics of how forms work first, so at least they understand how things work before getting into more advanced stuff where they can get totally lost without understanding the basics :)

Comment: Point is that I don't really get where the issue is currently @FluffyKitten... From what I've seen on internet, the way I did to get all checked checkboxes in a string is properly done so I don't get where I'm wrong??? In PHP?

Comment: @JuliaAlexandre There are lots of tutorials out there about how to process forms. My advice is to start with a standard form *without* AJAX (or serialisation!) and learn how that works. Once you understand the basics, you can learn about more advanced concepts. Here is one to get you started [Handling checkbox in a PHP form processor](https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-checkbox/), but if you Google form processing in PHP you will get more info :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Will check then. Just one last question though. Can you just confirm my current thought?

In JS, I declare variables and set them with any specific value, then with AJAX, it processes these variables through PHP ? And thus, I would just need to $_POST the desired variable, right? :D

Comment: "*so I don't get where I'm wrong???*" The problem is that you don't understand the basics yet, so you are trying to run before you can walk :) Knowing the difference between which elements you can submit is a much more basic problem before you even get into what you are trying to do here. Once you learn how basic form handling works, then you can start looking at how to use JS and ajax. @IncredibleHat - same answer :) If they don't know you can't submit a table, its time to go back to basic PHP form handling first.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Not at all!! I was saying that the OP doesn't (they are trying to submit the table element), and that's the reason why I thought your suggestion of serialisation was a bit too advanced for them at this stage. *They* need to go back to basics, not you!!

Comment: @FluffyKitten fully true as I started with a website template so not understanding everything right now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a form instead of a table. Check also the `formSubmit` function in this example for how to get the values from the form.
I have tested the belowe example and it works. In the PHP code you can get all the posted values ith `$_POST["name"]`, `$_POST["email"]`, `$_POST["checkedOnes"]`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      Je serai présent(e) / Nous serons présent(e)s :*
      <form onsubmit="formSubmit()">
        <label for="form-name">Name</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="form-name" name="name" /><br />
        <label for="form-email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="form-email" name="email" /><br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="choice[]"
          value="mairie"
          id="CheckboxGroup1"
        />
        <label for="CheckboxGroup1">Cérémonie civile</label><br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="choice[]"
          value="vin d'honneur"
          id="CheckboxGroup2"
        />
        <label for="CheckboxGroup2">À la santé des mariés !</label><br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      function formSubmit() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(event.target);
        var checkedOnes = formData.getAll("choice[]");
        var name = formData.get("name");
        var email = formData.get("email");
        console.log(checkedOnes, name, email);
        var data = { name, email, checkedOnes: checkedOnes.toString() };
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./php/form-process.php",
          data: data
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It does not help checking for the `isChecked` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox

**Update**
I have checked you latest code and there are at least two problems:

**1** The HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="form-process.php" id="contactForm">
```

This way, when the user clicks `submit`, you are sending directly a `POST` message to `form-process.php`, instead of calling the `submitForm()` function, which in turns would collect the necessary form data and send it to `form-process.php`.

So you should change the line to:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm()" id="contactForm">
```

This way the form data will be sent to the `submitForm` function which will extract the data and post it to `form-process.php`.

**2**
Another problem is that you are missing     `event.preventDefault();` from the beginning of the `submitForm` function, without it the page will be reloaded and the code will not be executed. So it should be:

```
function submitForm(){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(event.target);
    var checkedOnes = formData.getAll("choice[]");
    // Then the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks man! For now, it seems checkedOnes is an array with all checked checkboxes values; as I converted it into a string, just need to add this into AJAX then I think

Comment: @JuliaAlexandre Yes, your ajax request should be fine. You can just pass the checkOnes to it.

Comment: I've made a check with my forms and it seems an issue remains.
`console.log(name,email,msg_subject,message,adulte,enfant,strChkOnes);` gives me the right information as string for all variables; however when submitting the form, I don't get the information regarding strChkOnes even though it's the same process as for other variables...

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope it will help. I have not tested with the PHP and I can not see all your code, so it is a bit hard to say. You should anyway be able to get the posted values by their name in PHP. Also one more thing.. I am not sure how it your code now, but make sure that all the data you are collecting is in the same form, like in the example.

Comment: @JuliaAlexandre I have done a small change to the code, in fact the checkedOnes had to be converted to string. I have now tested the code also with PHP and it works. Please mark the asnwer if you found it useful and/or solved the problem.

Comment: It seems I follow your instructions step by step but I'm still facing the issue. Anyway I can share with you the entire code as I don't know where I might have miss something... Sorry for that btw

Comment: @JuliaAlexandre Yes sure, feel free to share. I can have a look

Comment: I have edited my code above with the full html, js and php code regarding the form. As you mentioned, I have tried to change the table as per your code but it didn't change a thing so I didn't convert it.
As per console.log, I have all the proper data ; when the form is submitted, I received all the data except those in regards with the checkboxes.

Sorry btw for the french text between quotes. Thanks for your help ; I might forget something in my code...

Comment: @JuliaAlexandre I have updated the answer according to your code.

Comment: For an unexplained reason, I still don't get the checkboxes string by mail...I have made all the updates you mentioned and still get the same result. Any idea?

Comment: **UPDATE** I have made a check by changing js code with `var name="alpha"` but I still get the real name input in the text box so I might suggest the form directly goes to php without using js variable, even though I made the 1st update you suggested

Comment: Make sure that you have changed the <form> tag content like in the example. According to what you are saying, it looks like you still might have - method="POST" action="form-process.php" - in it, instead of -  onsubmit="submitForm()" -. Also add - echo $Body; - in the PHP file before sending the email in $success ... What does it print on the page? For me it works and prints all the information including the checked boxes.

Comment: `<form onSubmit="submitForm()" id="contactForm">`

echo $Body returns nothing/empty value next to "Présent à :" where checkboxes values should appear on the website

Comment: Also make sure that you are serving the right and updated version of your file. For eample make a small change to the text and check if it is shown on the page.

Comment: I have found the issue, I updated with `<form id="contactForm">`